# Which version of Unity am I running?

Tags: unity, unity-2d

I just installed Ubuntu Natty beta 2 on my system. And I also keep regular track of the milestones of Unity in Launchpad. When I downloaded Ubuntu Natty beta the Unity version was 3.8.6. However few hours ago they released the 3.8.8 version.

I need to know the version since it will help me test the features which were added and other stuff.

How can I find out which version of Unity I am running on Ubuntu Natty beta 2?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Type into terminal:

```
unity --version
```

Hopefully that's exactly what you want.

Alternatively, click on the Applications tab in the Unity Launcher and search "Synaptic". You should see "Synaptic Package Manager", open it, and then search "Unity" in the search bar (or Quick Filter, as it's called). Your version should be listed underneath the "Installed Version" column.

Comment: Yup exactly what I want....thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

**For Unity-2D:**

You can run the following command in a terminal and you would know what version is installed in your system:

```
apt-cache policy unity-2d
```

or

```
dpkg -l unity-2d
```

**For Unity:**

Similarly for Unity,

```
apt-cache policy unity
```

or

```
dpkg -l unity
```